# Is there a ways to speed up beam_sql magic execution?

Tags: apache-beam

I'd like to give friendly exploratory environment to Data Scientists to do some early iteration on Beam data processing pipelines.

Jupyter notebooks seem like a great environment to do this.

However, I'm running into the problem that SQL commands are very slow to execute from Jupyter.

E.g. when using `beam_sql` even the simplest command only returning a few constants takes more than 60 seconds to execute:

```
%%beam_sql -o pcoll
SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) AS `id`, CAST('foo' AS VARCHAR) AS `str`, CAST(3.14 AS DOUBLE) AS `flt`
```

My understanding is that this is because a separate Java process is launched in the background for each SQL command?

Is there maybe some way to speed things up?

Or should I consider exploring Pandas Dataframes rather than SQL when I aim to provide a friendlier user experience to Python users in the context of Jupyter notebooks?

p.s.: the timing comes from following the ["Develop Apache Beam notebooks with the interactive runner"](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/interactive-pipeline-development) guide, so Jupyter runs on a GCP Dataflow Workbench.

Comment: It downloads the docker image that runs the Java expansion service when the image is not downloaded yet. When you run it later, it should be faster.